# How to use the @wordpress/date block in the Gutenberg editor?

Tags: block-editor

It seems like there is an out of the box Date block provided by Wordpress:  https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/packages/packages-date/

How can we enable/use this block, or another datepicker block, within the Gutenberg editor?

Comment: have you opened an issue on the gutenberg github repo? Not that this is offtopic, but you're 1000x more likely to get an answer there for gutenberg questions

Comment: Made a post on the Gutenberg support form here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-use-wordpress-packages/

Comment: This is not a block you can add in your editor. It‘s a component developers can use when building something for the editor.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I meant their github issues, they'll see it where you posted but they're likely to migrate you to the github repo issue tracker

Comment: @TomJNowell, I was initially going to post a GitHub issue. When opening a new issue, I chose the [question](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/new/choose) option, and was then [directed to the forms](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/new?template=Custom.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress does NOT provide date picker block by default but have date component inside core. You need to call relevant components for date picker to work. Here's code from core [Date Component](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/components/date-time/)

```
import { DateTimePicker } from '@wordpress/components';
import { getSettings } from '@wordpress/date';
import { withState } from '@wordpress/compose';


const MyDateTimePicker = withState( {
    date: new Date(),
} )( ( { date, setState } ) => {
    const settings = getSettings();

    // To know if the current timezone is a 12 hour time with look for "a" in the time format.
    // We also make sure this a is not escaped by a "/".
    const is12HourTime = /a(?!\\)/i.test(
        settings.formats.time
            .toLowerCase() // Test only the lower case a
            .replace( /\\\\/g, '' ) // Replace "//" with empty strings
            .split( '' ).reverse().join( '' ) // Reverse the string and test for "a" not followed by a slash
    );

    return (
        <DateTimePicker
            currentDate={ date }
            onChange={ ( date ) => setState( { date } ) }
            locale={ settings.l10n.locale }
            is12Hour={ is12HourTime }
            />
    );

} );
```